# Command text was not set for the command object

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I have this code that I am trying to work in it I am using VB.NET and MS ACCESS as DATA BASE..  As I go along with my code I have encountered many problems such as : Command text was not set for the command object.... Does any one have the idea on how to fix this and can you critique my code for possible mistake?? It will be a huge help for my project.... Thanks Ahead!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb


Public Class Form2

    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim Myconnection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\TrooTeaFinal\Database\Loginform.accdb"
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim result As Integer
    Dim imgpath As String
    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim sql As String



    Private Sub ChkBoxRegShowpass_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChkBoxRegShowpass.CheckedChanged
        If ChkBoxRegShowpass.Checked = True Then
            TxtRegpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = True
        Else
            TxtRegpass.UseSystemPasswordChar = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRegClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegClear.Click
        ComboRole.Text = ""
        TxtRegLastname.Text = ""
        TxtRegFirstname.Text = ""
        TxtRegUsername.Text = ""
        TxtRegpass.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRegExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegExit.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBack.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
        ComboRole.Text = ""
        TxtRegLastname.Text = ""
        TxtRegFirstname.Text = ""
        TxtRegUsername.Text = ""
        TxtRegpass.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click
        Try

            Dim OFD As FileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

            OFD.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif"

            If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                imgpath = OFD.FileName
                PBoxProfilepic.ImageLocation = imgpath

            End If

            OFD = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRegisterAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRegisterAccount.Click
        Try

            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

            PBoxProfilepic.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            arrImage = mstream.GetBuffer()
            Dim FileSize As UInt32
            FileSize = mstream.Length
            mstream.Close()

            conn.ConnectionString = Myconnection
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO member([LASTNAME], [FIRSTNAME], [Role], [USERNAME], [PASSWORD], [Profile]) VALUES (@LASTNAME, @FIRSTNAME, @Role, @USERNAME, @PASSWORD, @Profile)", conn)

            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", TxtRegLastname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", TxtRegLastname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", ComboRole.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", TxtRegUsername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", TxtRegpass.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profile", arrImage)
            Dim r As Integer
            r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If r > 0 Then
                MsgBox("User Record hass been Saved!")
            Else
                MsgBox("No record has been saved!")
            End If
            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You create a `cmd` object with both the sql/command text and connection as parameters to the constructor. Then you override them both in the next two lines. *Don't override them, you've already initialised them.* Especially when one of the overrides (`sql`) hasnt been initialised.

Comment: how do i fix that error do you have a sample to do it?

Comment: Just ***don't override them***; Delete the two lines where you override `cmd.Connection` and `cmd.CommandText`. (Why initialise them in the constructor AND then override them in the next two lines?)

Comment: All objects that have a `Dispose` method should be disposed of. The easiest way to do this is to use a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) which means that `conn` and `da` should be declared within the method (ie: Sub) not at the class level.

Comment: `MsgBox` is from VB6, you may consider using [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0#examples